# Why Jquery Date give different value in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a problem when i worked with Jquery `new Date` function.

My Jquery code -

```
alert(new Date('/2013' + " 12:30 am"));
if (!isNaN(new Date('/2013' + " 12:30 am"))) {
    alert('true');
} else {
    alert('false');
}
```

When i execute this code in `Chrome` it's always return me `true`, but on other browser like firefox it's give `false`.

When `alert` this jquery `new Date('/2013' + " 12:30 am")` code -

In Chrome it's give - `new Date('/2013' + " 12:30 am")` give - `Tue Jan 01 2013 00:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.

In Firefox it's give - `Invalid Date`.

Why this code return different value in different browser?

[Try Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tPTVz/2/)

Comment: just put `alert(isNaN(new Date('/2013' + " 12:30 am")))` outside the loop and see what it is returning

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox

Comment: This is pure JavaScript, I don't see any JQuery references at all. You should tag it with "javascript" instead.

Comment: @ubercooluk: Yes, i known this, but i asked why it's working like this?

Comment: @EthanKaminski: I added "Javascript" tag, please see it.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox when you call `new Date(string)` the static method `Date.parse(string)` is called.

But the string format that you used is not supported in Firefox, take a look at the MDN documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2Fparse

I don't know why Chrome accepts this format (I couldn't manage to find the official docs) but it's not cross-browser safe, I would suggest to use `new Date (year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, ms)` that is standard and cross-browser safe

Hope this helps