# Error while converting date string to Date object in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I am converting a simple dateString to Date object. The following code works perfectly on all browsers except Firefox.

```
var dateString = "02-24-2014 09:22:21 AM";

var dateObject = new Date(dateString);

console.log(dateObject.toDateString());
```

The Firebug console in Firefox says `Invalid Date`. What am I doing wrong here?

I also tried replacing `-` with `\`, but it didnt help.

Is it possible to do this without using any libraries?

Comment: Why the downvote? @Daksh: It is actually possible, I got it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/cTcNK/4/

Comment: By the way I did not down vote but it is a possible duplicate of the link i have given, it has the same question and it has an answer as well

Comment: Please find my answer below. It works in all browsers including Firefox.

Comment: Did you really have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox ???

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying :)

Comment: So what do you want now? will you close your question on your own or do you want me to give that answer here or something else? :D

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Looks like Firefox does not like the `-` in `dateString`.

Replace all occurrences of `-` with `/` using a regular expression and then convert the string to `Date` object.

```js
var str = '02-24-2014 09:22:21 AM';

str = str.replace(/-/g,'/');  // replaces all occurances of "-" with "/"

var dateObject = new Date(str);

alert(dateObject.toDateString());
```

Answer (score 4):

Try: `var dateString = "02/24/2014 09:22:21 AM"`

dd-mm-yyyy is not a standard date format in EcmaScript. Some browsers implement it, some don't.

You tried replaceing hyphens with baskslashes, but you need to replace them with slashes.

if a date with hyphens comes from your server or something you can replace them using `replace` method and regex:

```
var dateString = "02-24-2014 09:22:21 AM";
dateString = dateString.replace(/-/g, '/');
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try this:

var dateString = "02-24-2014 09:22:21 AM";

var dateObject = new Date();

dateObject.toDateString(dateString);

Comment: I think thats a very clean answer. +1

Comment: its not working in ie

Answer (score 1):

i will suggest you to use,

```
http://momentjs.com/
```

moment.js jQuery api.It works on all browers.
There are many ways to do same task. but easiest way is to add moment.js.

```
 var dateString=moment('date as string').toDate();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cTcNK/5/

Comment: That would be my last resort.

Comment: yes. . .There are many alternatives.

Comment: Well its easier than doing regex manually.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use the ISO8601 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format:  YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.

So: `new Date('2014-02-24T09:22:21')`

If the string is fixed... then split it and use Date constructor like

```
new Date('2014', '02' - 1, '24', '09', '22', '21')
```

Comment: No, the format is fixed, as in the question.