# weird Date() parsing error

Tags: javascript

So i have the following string "2013-12-10 23:33:05"

when i do `var d =  new Date("2013-12-10 23:33:05");` in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/38TuV/1/

d contains the right object and has no issue.

however in my sites when i do

```
var date = '2013-12-10 23:33:05';
var d =  new Date(date);
```

d is Invalid Data. whats even weird if you'll look in the fiddle, i also made that same copy as the second example and it seem to work

This is weird, its probably something specific to my page however i am logging `data` and it prints '2013-12-10 23:33:05' so i dont know ... Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder if there could be leading or trailing data that might mess it up?

Comment: Which other JavaScript resources are loaded on your sites?

Comment: nah no leading or trailing data i do console.log('|'+date+'|') no trailing, i am thinking its some plugin that changes how date works

Comment: jason Aller alot, and that's what i am going to test next

Comment: dumb question.. you mentioned dat**a** but your code shows dat**e** is this just a post typo?

Comment: yea type.. this is getting even weird i've disabled all other pluging and loaded files. and it still happeneds.

Comment: Can you copy a larger section of the enclosing code and add it to the question?

Comment: Found the issue !! The issue is with firefox(maybe with other browsers didnt check) Seems firefox date function cant parse the above string !! chrome does though.

Comment: Try replacing the space with the letter `T` in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure date will be in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS', try this on firefox

```
var date = '2013-12-10 23:33:05'.replace(' ', 'T');
var d =  new Date(date);
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox

Comment: No, don't do that. Parse date strings manually, there are too many issues to leave it up to Date.parse.

Comment: Try the above in Firefox and Chrome, you may find one treats it as UTC and one doesn't. Happy days.

Answer (score 1):

Before ES5, parsing of date strings by [Date.parse](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2) (which is the same as parsing using the [Date constructor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2)) was entirely implementation dependent. ES5 introduced a [version of ISO 8601](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) for compliant implementations, however not all browsers in use are compliant.

Therefore, the best way to parse a string date and time value is to parse it yourself. With the ES5 version of Date.parse, an ISO 8601 format string with no time zone will be treated as UTC, so:

```
function parseUTCDateTime(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D+/g);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(s[0], --s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5], 0));
}

parseUTCDateTime('2013-12-10 23:33:05'); // Wed 11 Dec 07:33:05 UTC+0800 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `dateclass.js` defined in JSFiddle external resources.

I removed it and it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/38TuV/2/

I don't know why you have it, perhaps it is a shim. Anyway, it also works fine without it in the console.

Using Chromium console (control-shift-J), it worked fine:

```
var date = '2013-12-10 23:33:05';
var d =  new Date(date);
undefined // chromium console is printing the return value of the assignment, undef is OK
date
"2013-12-10 23:33:05"
d
Tue Dec 10 2013 23:33:05 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Comment: yea, in the fiddle it work just fine for both the examples .. in my site however it does. i am starting to think its a plugin or something that change how Date works .

Comment: I have the dataclass.js because it helps with nice formatting and weight almost nothing. The issue is with firefox. chrome seems to be able to parse the above string while FF doesnt.