# Parsing Date with javascript in FireFox

Tags: javascript, date, firefox

I have strange date format like this `dMMMyyyy` (for example 2Dec2013). 
I'm trying to create Date object in my **javascript** code:

```
var value = "2Apr2014";
var date = new Date(value);
alert(date.getTime());
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wu4tD/3/)

in **Google Chrome** this code works fine but in **FireFox** it returns `Null`

Can anyone suggest something to solve this problem

Thanks.

Comment: Try `var value = "2 Apr 2014";` that will work in both chrome and firefox.

Comment: See [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for supported formats

Comment: I'd recommend using a date library like `momentjs` if you want to use a format like this

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just parsing it into the values `new Date` accepts, that way it works everywhere

```
var value = "02Apr2014";

var m = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

var month = value.replace(/\d/g,''),
    parts = value.split(month),
    day   = parseInt(parts.shift(), 10),
    year  = parseInt(parts.pop(), 10);

var date = new Date(year, m.indexOf(month), day);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Wu4tD/5/)

Answer (score 1):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wu4tD/4/) works in both firefox and chrome

```
var value = "02 Apr 2014";
var date = new Date(value);
alert(date.getTime())
```

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using something like [jQuery datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to parse your dates.

I haven't tested it but it seems you'd need something like:

```
var currentDate = $.datepicker.parseDate( "dMyy", "2Apr2014" );
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/immersion/QDM5F/)**

Just be aware of:

- d - day of month (no leading zero)
- dd - day of month (two digit)
- M - month name short
- y - year (two digit)
- yy - year (four digit)

---

However if for some reason you really wanted to do it yourself, then you could check out this link: http://jibbering.com/faq/#parseDate

It has some interesting examples on parsing dates.

Whilst not exactly what you want, the `Extended ISO 8601 local Date format YYYY-MM-DD` example could be a good indication of where to start:

```
  /**Parses string formatted as YYYY-MM-DD to a Date object.
   * If the supplied string does not match the format, an 
   * invalid Date (value NaN) is returned.
   * @param {string} dateStringInRange format YYYY-MM-DD, with year in
   * range of 0000-9999, inclusive.
   * @return {Date} Date object representing the string.
   */
  function parseISO8601(dateStringInRange) {
    var isoExp = /^\s*(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)\s*$/,
        date = new Date(NaN), month,
        parts = isoExp.exec(dateStringInRange);

    if(parts) {
      month = +parts[2];
      date.setFullYear(parts[1], month - 1, parts[3]);
      if(month != date.getMonth() + 1) {
        date.setTime(NaN);
      }
    }
    return date;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following [JavaScript Library](http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js) for uniform date parser across browser.

It has [documentation](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Wu4tD/8/)

code:

```
var value = "2Apr2014";
var date =new Date(dateFormat(value));
alert(date.getTime());
```