# javascript date not working moizilla

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, firefox

I am using javascript Date object to parse the required date to date format 
e.g

```
 var parse = '1-3-2018 6:07 AM'
   var dateOut = new Date(parse);
   console.log(dateOut)//in mozila it shows **Invalid Date**
```

where as in chrome , IE it works

results are :

'Wed Jan 03 2018 06:07:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)' //chrome console

'Wed Jan 03 2018 06:07:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)' //opera console

'Wed Jan 03 2018 06:07:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)' //IE console

Comment: Shouldn't you pass your var parse to the date. Looks like you are printing dateOut.

Comment: edited my question

Comment: The date to parse is not a part of any standard. Please use a standard formed string when parsing dates.

Comment: I am getting this date from backend its just an example

Comment: "yyyy-mm-dd" is the correct order, you've to reorder the date string.

Comment: Check out Dylan Watson post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788490/parsing-date-with-javascript-in-firefox

Comment: i know how to split date, come-up with good solution not fixes

Comment: Don't use the built-in parser, parse it yourself or use a library like [*Fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) or [*moment.js*](http://momentjs.com)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not work with that format. Parse only works for specific formats for each browser. You will need to Parse the date yourself or change the format that it is passed. There are lots of ways to implement a custom date parse to reformat. Quick examples: [Convert dd-mm-yyyy string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

var dateOut = new Date(2018,0,3,6,7);
   console.log(dateOut);

Answer (score 0):

FireFox does not work the with that format

***in chrome the below format wont work with 
new Date('31-12-2018 6:07 AM')   //invalid date***

The foolowing are the examples to worki with example

var today = new Date();

var birthday = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');

var birthday = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');

var birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17);

var birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17, 3, 24, 0);

reference from-
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date]