# jQuery countdown timer does not count down

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

I am trying to implement a countdown timer using jQuery. I have an end time and the timer should count down from it until the current time becomes same as it.

I get the end time from a web service which I fetch using PHP an the end time that I get looks like this `2015-07-15 17:29:31`.

My actual line of code is like this

```
var then=<?php echo $server_response; ?>;
```

which I changed in the fiddle for easy understanding like this

```
var then='2015-07-15 17:29:31';
```

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
var timer;
var then='2015-07-15 17:29:31';
var now = new Date();
//now.setDate(now.getDate() + 7); 

var compareDate=then.getDate()-now.getDate();
timer = setInterval(function() {
  timeBetweenDates(compareDate);
}, 1000);

function timeBetweenDates(toDate) {
  var dateEntered = toDate;
  var now = new Date();
  var difference = dateEntered.getTime() - now.getTime();

  if (difference <= 0) {

    // Timer done
    clearInterval(timer);

  } else {

    var seconds = Math.floor(difference / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;

    $("#days").text(days);
    $("#hours").text(hours);
    $("#minutes").text(minutes);
    $("#seconds").text(seconds);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="timer">
  <span id="days"></span>days
  <span id="hours"></span>hours
  <span id="minutes"></span>minutes
  <span id="seconds"></span>seconds
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/etfszz8e/)

Comment: JS debugging 101; check the console: `Uncaught TypeError: then.getDate is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) from string use `new Date(date)`.

See the changes:

```
var compareDate = new Date(then) - now.getDate();
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ instead of then.getDate()
```

In `timeBetweenDates()`

```
var dateEntered = new Date(toDate);
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Parse to date instead of using it as it is
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/etfszz8e/1/)

**EDIT**

Also change the way you're getting date from server. **Wrap it in quotes.**

```
var then = '<?php echo $server_response; ?>'; // String
```

Comment: I am getting NaN. In fiddle it works; What could be the possible reason? @Tushar

Comment: @SajeevC Can't say until I see the code. Looks like you are expecting something as `Number` and it is not

Comment: @SajeevC That's server side issue, it has nothing to do with javascript

Comment: Found out the culprit. compareDate produces NaN.  parseInt() didn't help solve me this issue. @Tushar

Comment: @SajeevC Can you please create `jsfiddle`

Comment: @SajeevC Don't see any `NaN`, http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/etfszz8e/3/ made some improvements

Comment: I think it's browser dependent. No issues in Google Chrome. Nan in Firefox. @Tushar

Comment: @SajeevC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox