# JavaScript validate date between 3 dates

Tags: javascript, datetime

```
var current_date = '2015-10-21 16:08:30';
var event_start_date = '2015-10-27 09:30:00';
var event_end_date =  '2015-10-28 18:30:00';

if(new Date(current_date) > new Date(event_end_date)){
    //Event has been ended
} else if((new Date(current_date) > new Date(event_start_date)) && (new Date(current_date) < new Date(event_end_date))){
   //Event is running. Event will close event_end_date
} else {
   //Event not started yet. Event will start event_start_date
}
```

Above JavaScript condition not working.

What is wrong with me?

**Notes :-** Mozilla firefox above code not working. Please check [JSFiDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chinmay235/2gbsnbu0/1/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: What's not working about it - now you've edited it to use `new Date` it seems to work fine to me.

Comment: @JamesThorpe this one not working. Can you please check manually it

Comment: [I did](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ljkzcq5/), and updated `current_date` to be before, between and after and successfully triggered all 3 conditions.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/chinmay235/2gbsnbu0/1/

Comment: @Chinu Seems fine to me - says event is running, which it should since the first date is between the other two.

Comment: @JamesThorpe i got it. Problem in mozila browser. Can you please check both mozilla and chrome yo will get the different.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki please check my question. This is not duplicate. If i am using only `date` then its working fine. But in `datetime` i getting wrong message.

Answer (score 0):

First convert the to javascript date format. for eg.

```
var current_date = new Date('2015-10-21 16:08:30'); //works in chrome but not in firefox
```

Then your conditions will work.

Please follow this: [new Date() is working in Chrome but not Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox)

Apparently Mozilla is not very much flexible. Check there documentation: [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Hello dear its browser issue. Thre is showing different different message in different browser. Can you please check mozilla and chrome

Comment: You are right. There problem in mozilla. How we fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Browser support for parsing string to Date object is inconsistent. There is no specification on formats, so this is why it works on Chrome but not on Firefox.

[See this link](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html) for a table of supported formats on each browser

I personally use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) framework to manipulate Dates on JavaScript, it's easy to use and has a consistent API that works on most browsers.

```
var current_date = '2015-10-21 16:08:30';

var momentDate = moment('2015-10-21 16:08:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```