# moment.utc doesn't work in IE and Safari

Tags: javascript, date, browser, safari, momentjs

I am trying to convert [Dropbox API date format](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs) to date one. In moment.js,

It doesn't work in following format now.

```
moment.utc("Sat, 21 Aug 2010 22:31:20 +0000")
```

It does work in following format if using date convert before using utc:

```
moment.utc(new Date("Sat, 21 Aug 2010 22:31:20 +0000"))
```

However, I can't use new Date method, because it can't be used in some other cases (string is not standardized) -- related [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox) question.

One possible way is to configure Dropbox input format, is there any other method to let moment.utc work without using new Date method?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

In the official docs of [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), it says:

> moment(String);
>
> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known ISO 8601 formats, then fall back to new Date(string) if a known format is not found.

Therefore, in order to go around the new Date pitfall and also apply ISO 8061. I can apply `moment()` firstly and then apply `utc()`.

```
moment("Sat, 21 Aug 2010 22:31:20 +0000").utc()
```

In that case, although the input string is not formatted as the same(But all follow ISO 8061), they can still be processed safely.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = moment.utc("20100821", "YYYYMMDD");
var day = d.day(); // 6
var year = d.year(); // 2010
var month = d.month(); // 7
var date = d.date(); // 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Moments.js issues a big fat *Deprecation* warning on your code. The gist of the problem is this: **if you don't provide an explicit date format, and your date format is not an ISO 8061 lookalike, moment.js gives up on parsing it and relies on new Date() in stead**. Which is brittle at best.

The solution is simple: you *know* the format Dropbox uses to return your date in. Simply specify it, and your problem is solved. Something like (actual format may need some tweaking)

```
var value = moment.utc("Sat, 21 Aug 2010 22:31:20 +0000", "ddd, d MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss Z");
```

Comment: However, I also need to the same code to deal with other format of date. So in my case, I can't simply add Dropbox format there.

Comment: I just tried another way to do it.   var value = moment("Sat, 21 Aug 2010 22:31:20 +0000").utc();   it seems to work! What do you think of it? @Paul-Jan