# Google Charts Gantt Error

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Based on this demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

I'm trying to create a gantt chart.

This is the code I'm using:

```
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["gantt"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawGantt());
function drawGantt() {
   var $ganttData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   $ganttData.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
   $ganttData.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
   $ganttData.addColumn('string','Resource')
   $ganttData.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
   $ganttData.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
   $ganttData.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
   $ganttData.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
   $ganttData.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

   $array.push(['0000050000000000110010002','ddd','MKT',new Date(2015,11 - 1,26),new Date(2015,11 - 1,30),daysToMilliseconds(daydiff(new Date(2015,11 - 1,26),new Date(2015,11 - 1,30))),25,null])
   $array.push(['0000050000000000110010001','Actividad 1','MKT',new Date(2015,11 - 1,10),new Date(2015,11 - 1,11),daysToMilliseconds(daydiff(new Date(2015,11 - 1,10),new Date(2015,11 - 1,11))),4,null]);
   $ganttData.addRows($array);
   var $ganttOptions = { height: 300, gantt: { trackHeight: 30 } };
   var $ganttChart = new google.visualization.GanttChart(document.getElementById('div-Actividades'));
   $ganttChart.draw($ganttData, $ganttOptions);
}
```

As a result, I have this non-understanding error:
[image]

This image is from Mozilla Firefox

using IE or Chrome, this is working fine.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The provided example does not work for me in any browser due to the following issues:

- since `google.setOnLoadCallback` function expects function callback,
  you need to replace `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawGantt());` with
  `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawGantt);`
- `$array` is not initialized,e.g. `var $array = [];`
- and last but not least,it's not an real issue but you could set`null` to `Duration` column, it will be calculated automatically based on `Start Date` and `Start Date` values

**Modified example**

```js
google.load("visualization", "1.1", { packages: ["gantt"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawGantt);

function drawGantt() {
   var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
   dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
   dataTable.addColumn('string','Resource')
   dataTable.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
   dataTable.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
   dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
   dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
   dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

   data = [];
   data.push(['0000050000000000110010002','ddd','MKT',new Date(2015,11 - 1,26),new Date(2015,11 - 1,30),null,25,null])
   data.push(['0000050000000000110010001','Actividad 1','MKT',new Date(2015,11 - 1,10),new Date(2015,11 - 1,11),null,4,null]);
   dataTable.addRows(data);
   var ganttOptions = { height: 300, gantt: { trackHeight: 30 } };
   var ganttChart = new google.visualization.GanttChart(document.getElementById('div-Actividades'));
   ganttChart.draw(dataTable, ganttOptions);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="div-Actividades"></div>
```

> The specified example works properly in Google Chrome (v46), Mozilla
>   Firefox (v41.0) and IE 9+

Answer (score 0):

Probably something in the javascript engine with firefox that is different from IE/Chrome, maybe the format of `new Date(2015,11 - 1,11)` ?

Look at [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox/3257513#3257513).

[Here is](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-date-format) some more interesting reading about formatting dates.