# jquery ui datepicker setdate only works on google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

My code:

```
<input type="text" id="testdate" name="testdate" value="2017-01-01" />

<script>
$('#testdate').datepicker();
$('#testdate').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
$("#testdate").datepicker('setDate', new Date('2017-01-01 12:00:00'));
</script>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g0uyok13/

In Google Chrome it shows 2017-01-01 in the text input area. In Firefox it shows today's date (atm 2016-02-24). I'd like it to work in Firefox the same way as it works in Google Chrome.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't line 5 read `$('#testdate').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yyyy-mm-dd');`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the time `12:00:00` . Dont forget that it is a datepicker you are using. Time has nothing to do with it.

Now the reason it works in chrome, i guess it is internal implementation of the browser. Mozilla discards the invalid date format while chrome tries and cuts it down...(This is purely my assumption, i dont base it on any documentation...yet)

**UPDATE**

Yes my assumption was right. [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) doesnt support the date format you have entered while chrome is more flexible and does support it. For universal date and time you can use this code:

```
$('#testdate').datepicker();
$('#testdate').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
$("#testdate").datepicker('setDate', new Date('2017-01-01T12:00:00Z'));
```

(Works in both browsers)

You can see also [new Date() works differently in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109894/new-date-works-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox) for more info on this

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the format of your date string to be in format:

```
$("#testdate").datepicker('setDate', new Date('2017-01-01T12:00:00'));
```

Firefox doesn't know how to parse the date with a space

Here is an extract from MDN

> dateString
>
> String value representing a date. The string should be in a
>    format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822
>    timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

You can see more info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

Your date is invalid in firefox...try this:

```
$('#testdate').datepicker();
$('#testdate').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
$("#testdate").datepicker('setDate', new Date(2017, 00, 01, 12, 0, 0, 0));
```

**NOTE:** Months are 0 based so 0 is January 1 is February etc...

That should work in firefox and chrome. I took the date format from this stackoverflow post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3257513/4028085)

Try this in firefox:

```
console.log(new Date('2017-01-01 12:00:00'));
```

Check your console it should show:

> Invalid Date

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4hessms/1/)