# Javascript issue with internet explorer, works fine in google chrome but not in ie,

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Hi i have an issue with ie not displaying my javascript, im a little puzzled as     it works fine in google chrome., i have tried f12 debugging and enabled     javascript but not with any luck so any help would be much appreciated. In chrome it shows correct amount of days and in ie it just says NaN.

```
var montharray=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")

function countup(yr,m,d){
 var today=new Date()
var todayy=today.getYear()
if (todayy < 1000)
todayy+=1900
var todaym=today.getMonth()
var todayd=today.getDate()
var todaystring=montharray[todaym]+" "+todayd+", "+todayy
var paststring=montharray[m-1]+" "+d+", "+yr
var difference=(Math.round((Date.parse(todaystring)-Date.parse(paststring))/(24*60*60*1000))*1)
difference+=" days"

document.write("<span style=\"color:#A4A4A4;font-size: 3em; \"> It\'s been  "+difference+" since the last incident.<\/span>")

}
//enter the count up date using the format year/month/day

countup('<?php echo $date1; ?>')
```

Comment: Welcome to web development.

Comment: @Virtyaluk poses a valid question: what is being returned by *$date1* also, which IE?  It works fine in Edge, unless your value is as the comment suggests (like in the format `'2016/02/25'`) which returns *NAN days*

Comment: Very strange to take a known date object...turn it into string, to turn around and then use Date.parse() on that string

Comment: Well, I repeat, what actually `<?php echo $date1; ?>` returns?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply iv been away working, the $date1 returns a mysql date, will be 2016/02/25 but i have tried changing the date to a different format with no luck

Comment: $date1=$row['date_of_incident'];

Answer (score 1):

What actually `<?php echo $date1; ?>` returns? Because it seems like `countup` expects 3 arguments but takes only 1.

Comment: You should post this not as an answer, but as a comment.

Comment: @vol7ron I haven't enough reputation to do so.

Comment: They should use a different metric.

Comment: @vol7ron Definitely! The system says I need 50 reputation to be able to post comments, but in the same time it says I need to leave some comments on people's posts to achieve 50 reputation.

Comment: You don't get reputation for comments

Answer (score 0):

If your JavaScript comment is correct, you're passing the value as 'YYYY/MM/DD', which is not the format your function expects.  Your function expects three different numbers/strings `countup('02','25','2016')`, not `countup('2016/02/25')`

The error occurs at your `var paststring  = montharray[m-1]+" "+d+", "+yr`.  This will result as `undefined undefined, 2016/02/25`, which is not a valid date.

The reason it works in Chrome is because `Date.parse('undefined undefined, 2016/02/25')` can actually produce the date, whereas other browsers (including Firefox) do the valiant thing and fail.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15110385) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3257513) for a little more information.

---

To fix your code, choose one:

- adjust your function to receive the input as you want to send it
- adjust your function call to send the proper arguments as defined by your function parameters
- use another library, like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)  to do all the calculations -- it's one of the best date management libraries available for JS

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the echo date is coming from mysql so im guessing its the wrong format, i have tried different formats but its still saying Nan days,

Comment: $date1=$row['date_of_incident'];

Comment: @MFC change your function to only have one date parameter. You don't need to break it into day, month, and year because you're not breaking it up.