# Date format "06-Feb-2013" working in chrome but not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have date in the format

```
06-Feb-2013
```

But when i pass this date through function `new Date()` like

```
 var dateSample = "06-Feb-2013";
 var d = new Date(dateSample);
 alert(d);
```

I am getting different outputs in *Chrome* and *Firefox* like.

**Chrome**
[image: Chrome alert]

**Firefox**
[image: Firefox alert]

**How to make my date format work in *firefox* also.?**
I can't change the date format.
If the solution is in native **Javascript**, it will be good.
**please help me?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [new Date() is working in Chrome but not Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slashes (`/`) are more widely supported then hyphens (`-`):

```
new Date("06/Feb/2013")
-> Date 2013-02-06T00:00:00.000Z
```

If you cannot hardcode the change from hyphens to dashes, you can simply `replace` them:

```
new Date("06-Feb-2013".replace(/-/g, '/'));
-> Date 2013-02-06T00:00:00.000Z
```