# How can I convert this string to a Javascript date in both Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have a string in Javascript: `'2008-03-09 18:02:29 UTC'`
I want to convert it into a date object. So I do the following:

```
> new Date('2008-03-09 18:02:29 UTC')
```

This works fine in Google Chrome (Version 49.0.2623.87, 64-bit):

```
> new Date('2008-03-09 18:02:29 UTC');
Sun Mar 09 2008 14:02:29 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

But when I do the same think in Firefox (Version 45.0.1), it fails:

```
> new Date('2008-03-09 18:02:29 UTC');
Invalid Date
```

Is there some code that I can write that will do this conversion properly in both browsers?

Comment: I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox

Answer (score 2):

Using hyphens (-) instead of slashes (/) works in WebKit browsers, but not in IE or FF. Beware the UTC parse of YYYY-MM-DD!

http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html

**Edit**: As the other answers have mentioned, moment is a great lib for this sort of stuff.

Comment: So does this work?  new Date('2008-03-09 18:02:29 UTC'.replace(/-/g, "/"));

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard about moment.js? Please see [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

You can solve this problem like this:

```
moment('2008-03-09 18:02:29 UTC')
```

And if you want Date object you can use this:

```
moment('2008-03-09 18:02:29 UTC').toDate()
```

Comment: @Omarjmh and now? If it works, why it should be a comment?

Comment: @Omarjmh you were right, thank you for the tip. This makes us improve in the next anwers.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add a library to your UI, try using moment.js (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/).

You can specify even a custom format.

**UPDATE:**

Try this:

```
moment.utc("2008-03-09 18:02:29 UTC", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

I have tried it both in Chrome and Firefox and it works beautifully.
Remember, if you are not using .utc(), the time gets your timezone, not UTC.

Comment: to the downvoters, at least explain why, doesn't this answer provides a solution to the question?

Comment: I downvoted because mentioning a library should be a comment, futher more the exact question is:  Is there some code that I can write that will do this conversion properly in both browsers?
please read the following: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
I will upvote the hell out of your answer if you give him the code!

Comment: fair enough, there you have an improved answer

Comment: Sorry, not trying to be a stickler, I got slammed for this when I was answering my first few too, I upvoted now, thanks!