# Browser discrepancies in parsing strings to Javascript Date objects?

Tags: javascript, date, cross-browser

My Javascript code tries to parse some strings into Date instances.

An example string would be `'2016-04-06 00:00:00 -0400')`.

Now here's where behaviour starts to differ between browsers:

In Chrome 49, `new Date('2016-04-06 00:00:00 -0400')` returns the correct Date object.

However in Firefox 45, the same code return `Invalid Date`.

Why does this difference exist, and how do I parse this sting consistently across browsers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox

Comment: can you try this this format:  ''2013-08-31T17:00:00Z'', otherwise, check out the link above

Comment: Thanks, folks. This answers my question.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox