# Angular2/JS - Date expression works only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, cross-browser

I just tested my app today with my FireFox browser after using Chrome all along, and I noticed my app is not working correctly.

I've done some searching and I found that the following expression recognized has "Invalid date" in FF/IE, and works in chrome:

```
this.future = new Date(this.travelData.created_at);
```

when console logging `this.future`, I get `Invalid Date` message.

While console logging `this.future` in Chroms returns:

```
Mon May 23 2016 19:56:48 GMT+0300
```

So I wonder, how I can make it work in FF and other browsers too, while `this.travelData.created_at` returns the following format from my API:

`2016-05-23 19:47:07`

Hope someone knows a solution to this browser strange error, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you would need to convert `this.travelData.created_at` to a valid date first.

See also [new Date() is working in Chrome but not Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox) and [new Date() works differently in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109894/new-date-works-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox)

Comment: Thanks, Just had to replace "-" with "/".