# Chrome auto incrementing invalid dates

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using new Date in javascript. In case of **firefox** if i try

```
 new Date('2016-02-31')
```

it gives me **invalid date** but if I perform the same action in **chrome**, it gives me

> Wed Mar 02 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

i.e. it is incrementing  the value to the subsequent month (2 days in this case).

Is it intentional or a bug in chrome?

Google Chrome version : Version 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit)

Firefox version : 41.0.1

Comment: use `MM/DD/YYYY` example `02/31/2016` format instead in firefox

Comment: Almost identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox

Comment: Not that identical, here the date is invalid