# convert string to Date Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Trying to convert a string to Javascript Date.
My string:

```
var fullDate = this.date + " " + this.time + ":00";
```

gives an output: **24/12/2016 02:00:00**

but trying to convert it in js Date object like:

```
 var k = new Date(fullDate);
```

gives the output: **Invalid Date**

or even: `var k = Date.parse(fullDate);`

gives the output: **NaN**

Any help is welcome.

*I was following instructions from  http://www.datejs.com/ so far*

Comment: Your date/time format is probably not matching your locale's format, and is not ISO... it should be either of those.

Comment: I don't know what the guidance on datejs.com says, but try reading some reliable documentation on this (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and checking what date formats are understood by the date constructor, it's not actually that many. Other libraries like MomentJS can parse dates in a wider variety of formats.

Comment: This is a good summary for this issue actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257460/new-date-is-working-in-chrome-but-not-firefox/3257513#3257513

Answer (score 5):

Your format is invalid. Valid format is `month/day/year`, so try:

```
var fullDate = "12/24/2016 02:00:00";
var k = new Date(fullDate);
```

Hope I could help!

Comment: if the string contains miniseconds,how to convert?

Answer (score 4):

I've just posted an answer/question for this.
[Here's my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123180/javascript-new-datestring-compatible-for-most-browsers-dec-2016)

In summary you need to format the string to a standardized format first and then you can use that string with the new Date(string) method. This work for many browsers (IE9+, Chrome and Firefox).

```
stringFormat = moment(dateObject).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
date = new Date(stringFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because you don't provide a valid date format for the `new Date`. So the date format is incorrect. The default date format in JavaScript is `dd/mm/yyyy`.

The date should be like(`mm/dd/yyyy`):

`12/24/2015`

And then you can use `var k = new Date(fullDate);`

A pure javascript solution to format the date(without `moment.js`):

```
var fullDate = "24/12/2016 02:00:00";
fullDate = fullDate.split(' ');

var date = fullDate[0].split(/\//);
var time = fullDate[1];

var newDate = date[1] + '/' + date[0] + '/' + date[2] + ' ' + time;
var k = new Date(newDate);
```