# how to make calculation of days based on 2 dates using angular12

Tags: javascript, angular, date, cross-browser, days

i am using angular12, here calculation of days based on 2 dates works fine with chrome, but the same thing fails in firefox.

TS:
Using Moment, gives invalid date error under firefox:

```
 getDaysCount(firstDate: any, secondDate: any) {
    let first = moment(firstDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
    let second = moment(secondDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
    return second.diff(first, 'days');
  }
```

console.log(this.getDaysCount('11-12-2022', '11-14-2022));

```
var Difference_In_Days = Math.ceil(Math.abs(secondDate - firstDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

this gives NAN in firefox but gives 2 in chrome.

Comment: *this gives NAN in chrome but gives 2 in chrome* - ?

Comment: sorry, updated question, i tried both ways but ntng worked in firefox

Comment: moment is deprecated. Use Luxon instead

Comment: thanks but cant anything be handled without adding luxon

Comment: If you want to keep using deprecated software, be my guest

Comment: thanks for invite, always headup to work on challenging part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15380132/5556177). Firefox requires the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. If you make the change, it works in both Firefox and Chrome.

FYI, you cannot use `Math.ceil` on strings, you need to convert them to milliseconds first.

```
getDaysCount(firstDate: any, secondDate: any) {
    const firtDateMs = (new Date(firstDate)).getTime();
    const secondDateMs = (new Date(secondDate)).getTime();
    console.log('First date: ' + firstDate, 'In ms:' + firtDateMs);
    console.log('Second date: ' + firstDate, 'In ms:' + secondDateMs);
    const Difference_In_Days = Math.ceil(Math.abs(firtDateMs - secondDateMs) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    console.log("Difference_In_Days: ", Difference_In_Days);
  }
```

To include negative numbers in the result, remove `Math.abs` from the function.

```
const Difference_In_Days = Math.ceil((firtDateMs - secondDateMs) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Firefox console:
[image]

Chrome console:

[image]

Comment: but here second date must be greater than 1st date, if second date is lesser than 1st date means i must get numbers in negative, like -1,-3 n so on

Comment: `firstDate - secondDate` is wrapped within `Math.abs`, which always return you positive number. If you want negative numbers, than remove the `Math.abs` from the function.